# WP8 emulator on Vmware player not running

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, vmware-player

I have created a vmware of windows 8.1 in order to develop a wp8 app.

**My pc specs** :

- i7 2670 (2.2)
- 8 gb ram
- win 7 64

**My VMware Player spec**:

- 60 gb hdd
- 4 gb ram

I have installed in the VMware Player visual studio 2012 update 4, and all the wp stuff.

When i am trying to build my project  i am getting this error:

```
 emulator Cannot assign the specified number 
 of processor for virtual machine  is out of range
```

I have searched on the internet but all links i have found refereed to parallels. Nothing helpful for VMware .

I have read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#windows) article. I have enabled hyper-v, but i am not sure if VMware can support hardware virtualization, which i think is needed.

My question are 2:

1. **Is these any possible solution to this problem?**
2. **If i got a device and try to debug on device i suppose that i will not have any problem. Am i suppose well?**

I will appreciate any help.

Thx for your time.

Comment: The Windows Phone 8.x emulators use Hyper-V, not VMWare Player. Out of curiosity, why are you using VMWare?

Comment: @Dai I have win7 pc. In order to develop wp8 app i need win8(as far as i know). So the easy way is to create a win8 machine with all the stuff for development (emulators, studio etc).

Comment: You need Windows 8 for WP8 development because of the requirement for Hyper-V. Note that you cannot run Hyper-V within another virtualisation platform like VMWare. You'll need to boot directly into Windows 8.

Comment: @Dai That's i was thinking. Thx for your advice. Very helpful. I suppose if i have wp8 device i could use VMWare?

Comment: Provided VMWare performs USB redirection (so the Windows 8 VM can communicate with the device), I don't see why not.

Comment: @Dai Please post the answer to up-vote it :)

Comment: @kostasch. I don't know if such feature exist in VMWare Player, but in VMWare Workstation in Virtual Machine/Processors settings you can tick `Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RIV` and then you can use WP8 emulator in hosted OS.

Comment: Try this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22283.how-to-install-hyper-v-on-vmware-workstation-10.aspx

Comment: @WiredPrairie thx for your try but the above solution is for workstation an not player.

Comment: Player is just Workstation minus a few features. Did you try it?

Comment: @WiredPrairie i think workstation is not free.

Comment: It's not free. But, Player, which is free, does 95% of what workstation can do, and most features can be enabled either through editing the config files or through UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments on your question, I'll explain:

You can perform Windows Phone 8.x development on Windows 7 or later provided you have a physical device, however if you want to use the Windows Phone 8.x emulators then you need to have Hyper-V available, this is because the WP8 emulators run as Hyper-V virtual-machines, side-by-side with your main operating system.

Therefore, to use the WP8 emulators you must be running **Windows 8 Pro**, **Windows 8 Enterprise** or **Windows Server 2012** (or later, e.g. Windows 8.1 Pro). The standard "Home edition" of Windows 8 does not include Hyper-V. [Read up about Client Hyper-V on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx).

Hyper-V requires hardware virtualisation and, as an accelerated platform with hardware requirements, will not run within another virtualiser  (this is in contrast to how you can run VirtualBox or [VirtualPC under Hyper-V](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/04/running-virtual-pc-under-hyper-v-beta.aspx)). You must be running Windows 8 Pro as your "root" operating system.

Answer (score 3):

VMWare Player v6. You need to tick `Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RIV` in virtual machine configuration for WP emulator running.
[image: VMWare Player virtualization configuration]
[image: WP emulator running inside VMWare Player]

Comment: Unfortunately in my case Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RIV are disabled and with no way i can enable them :( . I will check vmware player version you said. Also processors = 1 and disabled. I do not know why. +1 For your help :).

Comment: Yeap. I have tried to changes in the vmware file, restart vmware, restart pc. But is ok, i have ordered a wp8 device to do my job. Besides debug on emulator is very slow and generally i would go with emulator. I just wanted to start work before the device arrives. Thx a lot for your try.

Answer (score 0):

You actually also need to edit the .vmx file in VMWare Player in order for Hyper-V to be available to the Windows Phone emulator.

Give your VM >= 4GB RAM, 2+ processors, then open the .vmx file for the VM and add:

hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = “FALSE”

Then save, start the VM, and install Windows.

I'll also point out that this works flawlessly on my MacBook Pro Retina running a Hyper-V capable Windows distribution inside of Parallels and Visual Studio 2013 CE.